# Python send data

Tags: python, sockets, virus

I want to send some data from the server to the client. I thought about a socket connection but is this really save? What do I have to consider with the socket connection? I mean when the client is connected to the server he could also send a virus to the server. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what type of data a client wants to send. During the socket connection server and client sending each other bytes data. If you know exactly what should these bytes include you can discard other that not match your app.

Answer (score 0):

[image]If the security is an important consideration then I suggest looking into asymmetric cryptography - a cryptographic system that uses pairs of keys: public keys, which may be disseminated widely, and private keys, which are known only to the owner